# Definition of probabilistic metric space

Tags: probability-theory

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_metric_space)

> Let $D+$ be the set of all probability distribution functions $F$ such
>   that $F(0) = 0$: $F$ is a nondecreasing, left continuous mapping from
>   the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ into $[0, 1]$ such that $$
>      \sup_{x \in\mathbb{R}} F(x) = 1 $$
>
> The ordered pair $(S,d)$ is said to be a probabilistic metric space if
>   $S$ is a nonempty set and $$
>     d: S×S →D+ $$ In the following, $d(p, q)$ is denoted by $d_{p,q}$ and is a distribution function dp,q(x). The distance-distribution
>   function satisfies the following conditions: $$
>      d_{u,v}(x) = 0 \text{ for all }x > 0 \Leftrightarrow u = v (u, v ∈ S). $$ $$ ... $$

I wonder if $d_{u,v}(x) = 0 \text{ for all }x > 0$, whether $d_{u,v}$ is still a probability distribution function, since $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} d_{u,v}(x) =0$ not $1$?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I think there is some error in the Wikipedia article. The line should read $d_{u,v}(x) = 1$, all $x > 0$ $\iff u = v$.

Comment: Wikipedia articles that have no references or sources should be considered suspect.  At least Planet Math has some references ... http://planetmath.org/ProbabilisticMetricSpace.html

Comment: ... and PlanetMath says we need to have a 1 there, as their $e_0$ is $\chi_{(0,\infty)}$.